# URL BNF search part does not make sense

Tags: url, w3c, bnf

While implementing a Java regular expression for URL based on the [URL BNF](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/5_BNF.html) published by W3C, I've failed to understand the *search* part. As quoted:

```
httpaddress             h t t p :   / / hostport [  / path ] [ ?
                         search ]   
search                  xalphas [ + search ]   
xalphas                 xalpha [ xalphas ]   
xalpha                  alpha | digit | safe | extra | escape   
alpha                   a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k |
                         l | m | n | o  | p | q | r | s | t | u | v |
                         w | x | y | z | A | B | C  | D | E | F | G |
                         H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P |  Q | R |
digit                   0 |1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9   
safe                    $ | - | _ | @ | . | &  | + | - 
extra                  ! | * |  " |  ' | ( | )  | ,
```

*Search* claims it is *xalphas* seperated by a plus sign.
*xalphas* can contain plus signs by it self, as claimed by *safe*.
Thus according to my understanding , it should be:

```
search     xalphas
```

Where am I wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty clearly a mistake (+ is a reserved delimiter for URIs), but the BNF you're linking to seems to be out of date. Probably best to use the one [included at the end of the latest RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).